# Minimizing area in relative homology class

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geometric-measure-theory, minimal-surfaces

A well known result in geometric measure theory asserts that if $(M^{n+1}, g)$ is a closed Riemannian manifold and $\alpha \in H_n(M)$ is a nonzero homology class, then there exists a closed embedded minimal hypersurface $\Sigma$ (smooth outside a singular set of dimension less than or equal to $n-7$) minimizing area in $[\Sigma]=\alpha$.

My question is if this result can be (or has been) generalized for manifolds with nonempty boundary. Precisely, I wonder if the following is true:

> Let $(M^{n+1}, g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with nonempty boundary. Given $\alpha \in H_n(M, \partial M)$ a nonzero relative homology class, there exists an embedded and free boundary minimal hypersurface $\Sigma$ (smooth outside a singular set of dimension less than or equal to $n-7$) minimizing area in $[\Sigma]=\alpha$.

Comment: Yes, it works: double your manifold across the boundary and observe that the classical argument works equivariantly, with respect to the natural involution of the double.

Comment: Will the result surface be free boundary?

Comment: Doubling a manifold with boundary results in a manifold without boundary. Thus, the double of $\Sigma$ has no boundary.

Comment: Yes, I know that. What I meant was: apply the procedure for the double and obtain a hypersurface $\Sigma’ \subset D(M)$. Now let $\Sigma_0 = \Sigma’ \cap M$. Is $\Sigma_0$ minimal free boundary inside $M$?

Comment: Yes: Compare it with a competitor $\Sigma_1\subset M$. Then $Area(\Sigma_1)=Area(D\Sigma_1)/2\ge Area(D\Sigma_0)/2=Area(\Sigma_0)$, where $D\sigma_i$ is the double of $\Sigma_i$ inside $DM$, the double of $M$.

Comment: Another question: is the minimizer surface stable as a free boundary minimal surface?

Comment: Well, since it is an area-minimizer in its homology class....

Comment: I realized that the boundary of a minimizer may be empty, so it is not a free boundary hypersurface.